# Inserting rows of database into XML/XSD class C#

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate, xsd

Summary: I used xsd.exe to create a class off of an xml template. Let's suppose there's a class named human with two attributes: name(string) and id(int). My table, humans, has two columns named name and id. I'm trying to use SqlDataReader to read in the rows of my database and create a human object for each row. Is there a smarter way to insert each column into one of my attributes than this? Else, I would need many 'if' statements to check the name of each row and correlate it to an attribute.

```
XML Class
 public partial class human
    {

        private string name;

        private int id;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public int id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

** This is after a connect has been established to my database using SqlConnection

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tablename");
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   //Iterating through the columns of a specific row
   for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) 
   {
       human human1 = new human();
       string currentColValue = reader[i].ToString();
       string currentColName = reader.GetName(i);
       if (currentColName == "name" ) { human.name = currentColValue; }
       else { human.id = (int) currentColValue; } //Now you know it's the other attribute
       //Now you insert the human into a larger class or array
   }
}
```

As you can see, with a two column table it's relatively easy. But if I had a table with multiple columns, then it becomes way harder. Is there an easier way to do this?

It seems like NHibernate is the way to go, but the learning curve for it appears to be quite steep - would anyone mind giving me some sample code?

Comment: Use an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate.

Comment: I'll take a look into them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a full fledge ORM (Object Relational Mapping) like NHibernate and Entity Framework, I decided to use PetoPoco. In my opinion, it was much easier to learn over NHibernate as it was a simple class file.

Instead of the solution taking n number of if statements for n columns, it took only a single lines of code!

```
IEnumerable<human> humanList = (new PetaPoco.Database(connectionstring))
.Fetch<human>("SELECT * FROM dbTable");
```